# What's the earliest Android API level I can use Kotlin with?

Tags: kotlin, android-api-levels

I think the question is pretty clear but what's the earliest API level I can target on Kotlin?

Comment: I think you can use whatever API level you want, unless you use some Kotlin library which requires a higher level.

Comment: @marstran That is brilliant

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, any API level.

That's because Kotlin is compiled into bytecode for JVM 6 platform, which is supported in all Android API levels. So, unless you use any of the newer Android API in your Kotlin code, it does not require any specific API level.